# Accessing a HashMap value with a custom Pair Object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new to Java.  I'm writing a 2d game and I've decided to use a HashMap to store my map data because I need to support negative indices for my map coordinates. This is because the size of the map can grow during the game.

I have written a custom Pair class that stores final x and y values. I am using this Pair object as my key for my HashMap. My values are instances of a custom Cell class.

I have declared my HashMap as follows:

`HashMap<Pair, Cell> tiles = new HashMap<Pair, Cell>();`

Next, I add entries to my map using:

`tiles.put(new Pair(0,0), new Cell());`

0,0 is obviously my unique x,y coordinate for this cell.

How do I access the fields and methods of Cell using the .get() method of HashMap, specific to an individual Pair? Such as Pair(0,0) or Pair(0,1). If the key was simply a string or an int, I would have no problem. I just can't figure out how to format my key for an object with a specific coordinate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` method of the `Pair` class.  Right now, if you have two instances of `Pair` as such:

```
Pair p1 = new Pair(0,0);
Pair p2 = new Pair(0,0);
```

These two instances in your program would **not** be seen as equal, and hence if you said:

```
tiles.put(p1, XXX);
tiles.put(p2, YYY);
```

the behavior would be such that your map would have two distinct keys, with two distinct values - where I believe what you would want is one key, with the last value YYY after these statements execute.

After implementing `hashCode` and `equals`, you could write a static helper method that instantiates a new `Pair` with some given coordinates, and performs a map lookup:

```
static Cell lookup(int x, int y) {
    return tiles.get(new Pair(x, y));
}
```

Here's a basic Pair class to help you get started:

```
public class Pair {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Pair(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Pair)) {
            return false;
        }

        final Pair pair = (Pair) o;

        if (x != pair.x) {
            return false;
        }
        if (y != pair.y) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had the basic part of the Pair class correct. I just didn't override equals and hashCode. While I don't currently understand WHY I need to do this, I'm sure I will after I take a moment to read through it.

Comment: You need to tell Java how to distinguish objects - otherwise it uses the reference to compare.  Read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 1):

You just write `tiles.get(new Pair(0, 0))`, just like you did for put.

Comment: Without overriding hashCode and equals, I don't think this would work would it?  Wouldn't two Pair's with the same exact coordinates not be equal?

Comment: Sure, but the OP has given no indication that they haven't done that already.  The OP's issue appears to be with the syntax, not the hashCode and equals parts.

Comment: The OP did say he/she was new to Java so I doubt this is something they considered.  Having said that, who am I to argue :)

Comment: I know nothing about hashCode and equals other than what I've been reading up on this topic. This is my first foray into HashMaps. After I typed this question I suspected that this was the issue. I'm still a little unclear why you have to use the keyword new when accessing a key. My understanding was that you only use the word new when creating an instance of a Class. Enlighten me please. Very new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the methods `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` for your `Pair()` type. They are needed in order to use a type in a HashMap. Equals can just check that the 2 values are equal:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) return true;
    if(!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
    Pair p = (Pair)o;
    return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

For hashCode, you must generate a value that is unique:

```
private volatile int hashCode; // define this as a member of the class

@Override public int hashCode() {
    int result = hashCode;
    if(result == 0) {
        result = 17 * x + 31 * y;
        hashCode = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can access the cell at (0, 0) by simply calling

```
tiles.get(new Pair(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override hashCode(). Something like:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 17 * this.key + 31 * this.value;
}
```